# session getting destroyed after submission, why?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Troubles with a PHP session variable after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049767/troubles-with-a-php-session-variable-after-form-submission)

I use sessions on a forum to control user access and authentication and all the pages are access controlled but I have noticed a bug lately where when you submit a form on the forum, after submission all the sessions are destroyed...I dont know why. any help?

I am using tectite.com for form submission and it has a very long list of configurations and its code is huge so I dont know what it is in there thats causing it.

For the time being I have solved the problem in a very poor way which is pass my session value as a GET post.

Comment: Look at the code that handles the form submission. It's called debugging.

Comment: can you please throw some code...

Comment: What forum software are you using? or did you make your own? from scratch or with a framework? and indeed, if you made your own, can you throw the code up here so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: I am using http://www.tectite.com/ for form submission and it has a very long list of configurations and its code is huge so I dont know what it is in there thats causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into these similar stackoverflow questions:

[Troubles with a PHP session variable after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049767/troubles-with-a-php-session-variable-after-form-submission)

[php sessions create and destroy on submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831676/php-sessions-create-and-destroy-on-submit)

Hope this helps.